# DNS: Zone TrustAnchors secondary servers must respond to queries for the zone

Tags: windows-server-2019, dns-server

I'm trying to clear out every last error (and hopefully warnings as well) mentioned by BPA (Best Practices Analyzer) about my DNS server on Windows Server 2019 server.
Currently I have 1 error left:

```
DNS: Zone TrustAnchors secondary servers must respond to queries for the zone
```

There's also a warning, most likely related:

```
DNS: Zone TrustAnchors secondary server 10.10.1.2 should respond to queries for the zone.
```

(where 10.10.1.2 is the IP of the only interface the DNS server listens on.)

Who has any ideas/suggestions/tips?

Comment: a DNS zone needs two nameservers that's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @djdomi I do have 2 nameservers, the other one being on 10.10.1.3. BPA doesn't report anything wrong on that one.

Comment: but it tells that 1.2 is not responsible for the zone or does not work, you have to clarify what is wrong with the service

Comment: Well... There's nothing wrong with the service AFAIKT, but we would like to get that last error gone out of BPA .

The DNS service (including sync between 1.2 & 1.3) seems to be fine.

It seems to be a rare error, since I get < 10 hits on Oogle when I search for it, none of them providing a solution (as in: the error message disappears) for me...